# XWin headers and libraries (devel) path in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, xorg

What is the path of the XWin headers and libraries (Devel) in Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are developing an X11 client using libX11, headers are in /usr/include/X11 and libraries in /usr/lib

You will need to have the [libX11-devel](http://cygwin.com/packages/x86/libX11-devel/libX11-devel-1.6.2-1) package installed.

The portable way to discover this is using pkg-config, e.g. `pkg-config --cflags --libs x11`